# WooCommerce custom taxonomy as meta?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugins, post-meta

I have created two custom taxonomies:

(slug) = language

(slug) = location

On the single product page I would like to display these two as meta below the "Categories" and "Tags."

Example: [image: screenshot]

I found that the meta is displayed by `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php`

I copied this files under my theme `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`

and added the following after the categories and tags, before the

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>
```

It doesn't work because I think the "`echo $product->get_terms`" doesn't actually get the custom taxonomy.

```
<!-- Display custom taxonomies as meta -->
<?php
    $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'language' ) );
    echo $product->get_terms( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Language:', 'Languages:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
?>

<?php
    $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'location' ) );
    echo $product->get_terms( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Location:', 'Locations:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
?>
```

Is there a pre-made function to call a custom taxonomy, such as "get_taxonomyslug"? I tried but it didn't work. Or do I have to define them by myself?

If someone could help with code or some pointers it would be great. Please include file location with each code snippet as I am still quite new to this and might not know where to put them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant /wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php without the "templates"

Comment: I'd suggest using WooCommerce's product attributes... which are really just taxonomies anyway. Does `$product->get_terms()` exist as a method? I think you just mean WordPress' default [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking! Thank you for your answer. I cannot use 'product attributes' because I am using the Product Vendor plugin together with the Bulk Variations plugin, which means that all vendors can see each others' attributes. With 250+ vendors selling across different categories, this makes the Bulk Variations feature very cumbersome so I cannot use Attributes.

I guess I should have explained this in my main post.

re: "get_terms()" yes, I was trying to find a way to call the custom taxonomy, but it didn't work. Any way to do the above?

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you can't use »product attributes« and have two additional »custom taxonomies« just use [get_the_term_list()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) to achieve what you want. The basic usage would be to place below code where you want to show the additional output - take a look at the codex page for information about formatting options.

**Code:**

```
//Show list of post specific terms from taxonomy language
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'language', 'Language: ', ', ', '' );
//Show list of post specific terms from taxonomy location    
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', 'Location: ', ', ', '' );
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP is searching for. `get_terms()` should return an array, so can't be echoed.

Comment: @helgatheviking After you cleared it up it was pretty obvious.